# Get substring in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have a problem to do a htaccess file. I have an URI like this :

```
http://www.exemple.com/?fileName=fileName&otherString=otherString
```

And I would like to execute a command like this :

```
<If "file('fileName') !~ /otherString/">
    # do something
</If>
```

Is it possible to get fileName and otherString from URI ?

Is it possible to get `%{QUERY_STRING}` substring with regex ? or other ?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :**

I don't want to rewrite the URI (for the moment). The URI contain name of a text file ("fileName"), and an information in this file ("otherString"). I want to access this file and verify if the information is presents into it. And if so, do something I want.

I have these two regex :

```
/\?file\=(.*)\&/
/\&otherString\=(.*)$/
```

Which isolate the two parts I want in the URI. But I don't know how to use it (and if it's possible) to get and manipulate parts of URI as string.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add an example of the rewriting you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is not the best tool for this.

You can extract, from the query string, the values of the parameters you want with a regular expression like `%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(?:^|&)fileName=([^&]+)&otherString=([^&]+)/`. The value of *fileName* can be retrieved with the backreference variable `$1` and, for *otherString*, `$2`.

But it seems you can't reuse a backreference variable in a regexp.

So, for an exact match:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(?:^|&)fileName=([^&]+)&otherString=([^&]+)/ && file(%{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/' . $1) == $2">
```

(change `==` to `!=` for a non-match)

If the string can be found anywhere in the file, the best I've been able to find is:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(?:^|&)fileName=([^&]+)&otherString=([^&]+)/ && file(%{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/' . $1) -strmatch '*$2*'">
```

(add `!` before `file(` for its negation)

It may be a good idea to add a test like `&& -s %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/' . $1` between the two others to avoid some useless noises in error log.